# [Selenium]I want to save all images from my pinterest boards

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I would like to save all images from a pinterest board. I am having trouble writing the process to go back to the board and go to the next image after downloading the image, and I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

Board example:https://www.pinterest.jp/aku_ma/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3/

1. Login
2. Access the board ←I have done this.
3. Access the page of the image in the board
4. Press the download button and save to the specified path
5. Return to the board and access the page for the next image

#### ボードにアクセスするまでのコード

```
import os
import selenium
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

url ='https://www.pinterest.jp/aku_ma/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%E3%82%A2%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3/'
profilefolder = '--user-data-dir=' + '/Users/t/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default'
emailAdress = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
passwordNumber='xxxx'
foldername="/Users/t/Desktop/koreanLikeImages"
speed = 1

options = Options()
# options.add_argument('--headless')
DRIVER_PATH = "./chromedriver" # My ChromeDrivers Path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

loginButton = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[data-test-id='login-button']") 
loginButton.click()#Push at login button
time.sleep(1)

#Enter ID,Pass
email = driver.find_element(By.ID,"email")
email.send_keys(emailAdress)

password = driver.find_element(By.ID,"password")
password.send_keys(passwordNumber)

# Push The Red Login Button
redLoginButton = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "SignupButton") 
redLoginButton.click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.get(url)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Please show the the HTML with some of the elements if you can. Are you able to download the images, what is the next issue?

Comment: I tried to get all image elements using find_elements.

But it tells me that the element cannot be found. I must be specifying it wrong.

Comment: What path did you use in `driver.find_elements()` to try finding all the images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps 3, 4 and 5 are not necessary because when you are in the main page the high resolution links are already loaded in the html. For example this is the html code of an image

```
<img ... srcset="
https://i.pinimg.com/236x/80/c8/ec/80c8ec56386197561bac4c4e40d331b8.jpg 1x,
https://i.pinimg.com/474x/80/c8/ec/80c8ec56386197561bac4c4e40d331b8.jpg 2x, 
https://i.pinimg.com/736x/80/c8/ec/80c8ec56386197561bac4c4e40d331b8.jpg 3x, 
https://i.pinimg.com/originals/80/c8/ec/80c8ec56386197561bac4c4e40d331b8.jpg 4x">
```

As you can see, each image has 4 urls, each url is the image at a different resolution, and the 4x has the highest resolution. Using `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url)` we can download the file associated to url, so we can download the images in high quality directly on the homepage.

```
import urllib.request
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException

foldername = 'C://Users//gtu//Desktop//folder//'
urls = []
new_images = False

while 1:
    images = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'img[srcset]')
    for img in images:
    
        try:
            url = img.get_attribute('srcset').split(',')[-1].split()[0] # [-1] selects the larget resolution
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            # as you scroll down old images are removed from the html, so it may raise this error but it's not a real problem
            continue
        
        if url not in urls:
            # scroll down so that new images are loaded
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center", behavior: "smooth"});', img)
            urls.append(url)
            print(url)
            new_images = True
            file_name = url.split('/')[-1]
            # download the image
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, foldername + file_name)
            time.sleep(1)
    
    # if there are no new images it means we reached the bottom of the page
    if not new_images:
        break
    else:
        new_images = False
```